# Run python code for specific time

Tags: python, twitter-oauth, twitter-streaming-api

i have following code:

```
def gen_stream():
    stream  = twitter.STREAMING_API(key=1, payload={})
    for tweet in stream.run():
        yield tweet
def pipeline():
    for tweet in gen_stream():
        tweet_id=tweet.get('id')
        print(tweet_id)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipeline()
```

how can i run code for 1 minute only. 
I have tried using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    endtime=time.time()+60*1
    while time.time()<endtime:
        pipeline()
```

but this code keeps yielding tweet ids after endtime. How can I run `pipeline` for specified time?

P.S The `gen_stream()` works fine.

Comment: The time control logic needs to be in the pipeline() method itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code enters the `pipeline` function and loops in it forever.

let `pipeline` accept an `endtime` parameter

```
def gen_stream():
    stream  = twitter.STREAMING_API(key=1, payload={})
    for tweet in stream.run():
        yield tweet

def pipeline(endtime):
    for tweet in gen_stream():
        if time.time() > endtime:
            break
        tweet_id=tweet.get('id')
        print(tweet_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    endtime=time.time()+60*1
    pipeline(endtime)
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking. On mobile, so tough to type out. The only correction I would make is remove the endtime argument and just add if before the for loop

Comment: @ Haleemur Ali Thankyou. The code works but it is not returning to the command line.It just stops printing. Can you suggest me a way to return to command line

Answer (score 0):

You must spawn pipeline in separate thread or process and kill it from outside. Nice is to use pub sub pattern and nicely disconnect from the stream.

Pass parameter to pipeline but it will not close connection nicely.